# Optimizing Haskell text processing

Tags: optimization, haskell, nlp

I'm writing some simple character-counting routines in Haskell, storing the stats in a new datatype:

```
data Stat = Stat {
    stChars    :: !Int,
    stVowels   :: !Int,
    stPairEL   :: !Int,
    stWords    :: !Int
}
```

I'm running this over hundreds or thousands of plain-text files, each about 50K--100K.

```
tabulateFile :: FilePath -> IO Stat
tabulateFile path = do
  putStrLn path
  contents <- L.readFile path
  return $! tabulateText ' ' contents defaultStat
```

Instead of using fold-left, I'm using primitive recursion so I can keep around the previous character.

```
tabulateText :: Char -> L.ByteString -> Stat -> Stat
tabulateText lastChr bs stat =
  case U.uncons bs of
    Nothing -> stat
    Just (chr, newBs) ->
      tabulateText lchr newBs (countChar lastChr lchr stat)
        where lchr = toLower chr

{-# INLINE countChar #-}
countChar :: Char -> Char -> Stat -> Stat
countChar !lastChr !chr !(Stat stChars stVowels stPairEL stWords) =
  Stat
    (stChars  + 1)
    (stVowels + (countIf $ isVowel chr))
    (stPairEL + (countIf (lastChr == 'e' && chr == 'l')))
    (stWords  + (countIf ((not $ isLetter lastChr) && isLetter chr)))

isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel c = Set.member c vowels

vowels = Set.fromAscList ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', ...] -- rest of vowels elided
```

Right now, it's more than twice as slow as running `cat * | wc`, but my instinct tells me that the file I/O should outweigh the CPU time needed by a good margin. Simply using `cat * | wc` processes about 20MB/s with a hot cache, but using my Haskell program (compiled with `-O`) runs at less than 10MB/s, even after some basic optimization. Profiling tells me that most of the time is spent in `tabulateText` and `countChar`.

Is there something I'm missing that I could optimize here?

**Edit:** Complete file pasted to http://hpaste.org/74638

Comment: Can you post the complete file to some hpaste and post here the link. It includes lots of missing functions and I dont want to implement those in order to be able to run your code.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't get it up sooner. I've added the link to the end of the question.

Answer (score 10):

You should provide the imports so someone can compile the code. However, there's several things here that look likely:

- Compile with `-O2 -funbox-strict-fields` (to get the benefit of strict fields)
- tabulateText should be strict in `lastChr`, and `stat`
- Set.member seems like a very expensive way to do equality comparisons. Use a jump table.

E.g.

```
isSpaceChar8 :: Char -> Bool
isSpaceChar8 c =
    c == ' '     ||
    c == '\t'    ||
    c == '\n'    ||
    c == '\r'    ||
    c == '\f'    ||
    c == '\v'    ||
    c == '\xa0'
```

which will inline and optimize very well.

Not sure what `countIf` does, but it loosk bad. I suspect its an `if` and you return 0? 
How about:

```
Stat
   (a + 1)
   (if isVowel c then a + 1 else a)
   ...
```

Then look at the core.

Comment: About jump tables, I'm not clear what will or will not optimize to a jump table. Is the documentation on that? And will that work for multi-byte characters? I'm using `isSpace` from Data.Char. I assume that's already optimized?

Comment: Making `lastChr` strict in `tabulateText` doubled the runtime, probably because it was a net savings to not run `toLower` when not needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as U
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Word
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative 

data Stat = Stat {
    stChars    :: !Int,
    stVowels   :: !Int,
    stPairEL   :: !Int,
    stWords    :: !Int
} deriving Show
defaultStat = Stat 0 0 0 0

{-# INLINE  tabulateFile #-}
tabulateFile :: FilePath -> IO Stat
tabulateFile path = newTabulate <$> L.readFile path

{-#  INLINE newTabulate #-}
newTabulate :: L.ByteString -> Stat 
newTabulate = snd . U.foldl' countIt (' ',defaultStat) 
    where 
        {-#  INLINE countIt #-}
        countIt :: (Char,Stat) -> Char -> (Char,Stat)
        countIt (!lastChr,!Stat stChars stVowels stPairEL stWords) !chr = 
            (chr,Stat
                (stChars  + 1)
                (if isVowel chr then stVowels + 1 else stVowels)
                (if (lastChr == 'e' && chr == 'l') then stPairEL + 1 else stPairEL)
                (if ((isSpace lastChr) && isLetter chr) then stWords+1 else stWords))

{-# INLINE isVowel #-}
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel c = 
    c == 'e' ||
    c == 'a' ||
    c == 'i' ||
    c == 'o' ||
    c == 'u' 



main:: IO ()
main = do 
    stat <- tabulateFile "./test.txt"
    print stat
```

Most of the optimizations as suggested by Don is included along with using efficient foldl'. 
The performance is slightly slower than cat + wc, but it is ok as you are doing some more computation. I have not tested it on very big file but it should work comparable to cat + wc.

Compile with `-O2 -funbox-strict-fields` to get optimized code.

I will change it more after looking into the core and see if more optimizations are possible. 
One possible point of optimization is having if conditions out of the constructor while constructing stat, for example if `chr` is a vowel then it is already a `letter` so you don't need the other if in stWords etc, but that will really blow up your code, but you can try and see if it really helps on large files.

Answer (score 0):

After testing other alternatives, it seems that the high CPU usage was mostly because I was using Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8. I shaved a negligible bit of runtime off by modifying the data structures in `tabulateText` to use `foldl` over the UTF8 ByteString.

Given that, I parallelized the program over the files, and was able to sometimes get 7x speedup on my machine.

I first wrapped `tabulateFile` with an `unsafePerformIO`:

```
unsafeTabulateFile :: FilePath -> Stat
unsafeTabulateFile f =
  unsafePerformIO $ tabulateFile f
```

and then used `Control.Parallel.Strategies` to do `parMap rseq unsafeTabulateFile files`.